# hg pull abort unknown parent

Tags: mercurial, mozilla

I'm trying to pull from an hg repo but I seem to be getting the following error:

```
pulling from http://hg.mozilla.org/qa/mozmill-tests
searching for changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
transaction abort!
rollback completed
abort: data/tests/endurance/testBookmarks_AddAndRemoveBookmarkViaAwesomeBar/test1.js.i@2daf2ef33d4b: unknown parent!
```

And hg verify seems to return

```
759 files, 2820 changesets, 5082 total revisions
2688 integrity errors encountered!
(first damaged changeset appears to be 54)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I've cloned this repo and it worked ok. Do you have any local modifications in your clone? If not, you could just reclone the repo. Otherwise I suggest you to refer to the [wiki page about repo corruption](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RepositoryCorruption).

Comment: I re cloned the repo too, The re clone works fine. I wanted to figure out how to fix the original.